# SQL Server Data Tools and Visual Studio Issue

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-data-tools

I have just installed vs2010 sp1 ultimate, sqlserver 2012 and the latest version of sqlserver data tools.  I have opened up a solution from source control and receive a bunch of error like the following when trying the build the database project.

SQL71566: Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlFilegroup cannot not be set on both the Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlTable and the clustered Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlPrimaryKeyConstraint.

Running on Windows 7 professional, 64 bit

This is working fine for other members of the team and they all seem to have the same setup as me.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling vs2010 and ssdt

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug to which MS has not yet delivered a fix:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/765217/when-compiling-vs2010-database-project-in-vs2012-i-receive-error-sql71566

Comment: i saw this post but this does not explain why it is working for the others and not me.

Answer (score 9):

I was receiving this error with the November 2012 SSDT release but only when I moved a project from a 32 bit vista machine to a 64 bit vista machine. I was able to get my project to build by enabling the project setting "Enable extended Transact-SQL verification for common objects.". Enabling this setting in the past has caused other issues so I am not sure if this will surface other problems in this environment.